# How to prove that one of $2,3,6$ is a square modulo every prime $p$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

How to prove that one of $2,3,6$ is a square modulo every prime $p$?

I am thinking in terms of quadratic reciprocity but not getting any clue.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1234614/242)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what is
$$ (2|p) (3|p)(6|p) \; ? $$

Comment: Ohh ok $(6|p)=(2|p)(3|p)$ if $p \neq 2,3$ then it is always $1$. Thanks